# Linq query reporting 'invalid column name' on computed column in EF4.2

Tags: linq, entity-framework

I have a table that contains a (potentially) long string column and so to avoid having to pull in the whole string during LINQ queries just to check for length, I created a computed column in the table called HasContent using the formula:

```
(case when len([Html])>(0) then CONVERT([bit],(1),0) else CONVERT([bit],(0),0) end)
```

that produces a *Boolean* (aka SQL *Bit*) result.

In the Database-first EF4.2 edmx file, I get in the SSDL content:

```
<Property Name="HasContent" Type="bit" StoreGeneratedPattern="Computed" />
```

In the CSDL content:

```
<Property Type="Boolean" Name="HasContent" Nullable="false" annotation:StoreGeneratedPattern="Computed" />
```

and in the CS-Mapping:

```
<ScalarProperty Name="HasContent" ColumnName="HasContent" />
```

I'm using DbContext as opposed to ObjectContext in EF and the class includes (without any annotation) a Boolean property for HasContent.

For testing I have created a simple LINQ query:

```
var objContentItem = objDataContext.FirstOrDefault(x => x.ID == 2);
```

The solution compiles without errors, but executing the above query throws an error:

```
System.Data.EntityCommandExecutionException: An error occurred while executing the command definition. See the inner exception for details. ---> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Invalid column name 'HasContent'.
```

Quite why this should happen is a mystery, but I was wondering if there is something else I should be doing (annotation in a buddy class for example) to make this column visible to LINQ.

EDIT:

SQL Server Profiler BatchCompleted result:

```
SELECT TOP (1) 
[Extent1].[ID] AS [ID], 
[Extent1].[Html] AS [Html], 
[Extent1].[HasContent] AS [HasContent]
FROM [dbo].[ContentItems] AS [Extent1]
WHERE 2 = [Extent1].[ID]
```

Comment: Can you check generated SQL query (with some profiler) and add it to your question? Also make sure that you are querying correct database.

Comment: Ladislav - I've appended the SQL Profiler output. I didn't think it had properly touched the database, so it was instructive to use the profiler.

Comment: HasContent / blnHasContent? The column is just not in the table in that database, it is a regular SQL exception. Maybe it was a different instance of the database?

Comment: A slip on my part: I edited out the Hungarian prefixes that I generally use to make the question clearer for normal folk. I've now changed the two remaining instances of blhHasContent to HasContent in the question.

Comment: Does the SQL query run (e. g. run int through management studio) or does it produce the same error? As a side note, you should be able to reference the length of a string in LINQ queries with the normal Length property. I see no benefit to the computed column approach.

Comment: Are you trying to query the server with HasContent or the local data store.  If the former, HasContent shouldn't be a column in EF.Net (nor should it necessarily be in your EDMX file), but instead should be the first part of your IQueryable<T> definition.

Secondly, I see no reason to even include HasContent property in edmx.  It's much simpler (and much less noise, IMO) to just use HasContent in your partial class and not have it included in your model.  You can still use it with LINQ when querying data persisted locally.

Comment: Or, you might want to check that your case when has an alias (not included in your example) if that's part of the SQL on the server.

Answer (score 0):

Table should be included before FirstOrDefault method.

var objContentItem = objDataContext.Tablename.FirstOrDefault(x => x.ID == 2);